# gulp.js - refresh on file save terminates with error

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I'm *very* new to `gulp.js`. I was recently placed onto a team who has been using gulp for over a year and asked to fix the following issue: When I run `gulp`, it executes successfully and displays the correct content on the local host. While the web application is being hosted. However, when I edit and save a file it causes gulp to terminate with an error. The page attempts to reload but fails. The following error message is logged in the termianl:

```
Error: EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir 'C:\Users\<user>\flex-force-tools\client
at Error (native)
```

A quick Google search wasn't much use. I tried to familiarize myself with gulp functions as well but there's much more going on with this project than I currently understand.

Here's some information that may be helpful:

**Gulpfile.js**

```
'use strict';

var _ = require('lodash')
  , buildConfig = require('./build.config')
  , config = {}
  , gulp = require('gulp')
  , gulpFiles = require('require-dir')('./gulp')
  , path = require('path')
  , $, key;

$ = require('gulp-load-plugins')({
  pattern: [
  'browser-sync',
  'del',
  'gulp-*',
  'karma',
  'main-bower-files',
  'multi-glob',
  'plato',
  'run-sequence',
  'streamqueue',
  'uglify-save-license',
  'wiredep',
  'yargs'
  ]
});

_.merge(config, buildConfig);

config.appFiles = path.join(config.appDir, '**/*');
config.appVersionFile = path.join(config.versionDir, 'VERSION');
config.appFontFiles = path.join(config.appDir, 'common-elements/fonts/**/*');
config.appImageFiles = path.join(config.appDir, 'common-elements/images/**/*');
config.appMarkupFiles = path.join(config.appDir, '**/*.jade');
config.appScriptFiles = path.join(config.appDir, '**/*.js');
config.appStyleFiles = path.join(config.appDir, '**/*.less');

config.buildDirectiveTemplateFiles = path.join(config.buildDir, '**/*directive.tpl.html');
config.buildJsFiles = path.join(config.buildJs, '**/*.js');

config.buildTestDirectiveTemplateFiles = path.join(config.buildTestDir, '**/*directive.tpl.html');
config.buildE2eTestsDir = path.join(config.buildTestDir, 'e2e');
config.buildE2eTests = path.join(config.buildE2eTestsDir, '**/*_test.js');
config.buildTestDirectiveTemplatesDir = path.join(config.buildTestDir, 'templates');
config.buildUnitTestsDir = path.join(config.buildTestDir, config.unitTestDir);
config.buildUnitTestFiles = path.join(config.buildUnitTestsDir, '**/*_test.js');

config.e2eFiles = path.join('e2e', '**/*.js');
config.unitTestFiles = path.join(config.unitTestDir, '**/*_test.js');

for (key in gulpFiles) {
  gulpFiles[key](gulp, $, config);
}

gulp.task('dev', ['build'], function () {
  gulp.start('browserSync');
  gulp.start('watch');
});

gulp.task('deploy', ['build']);
```

**Gulp versions in package.json**

```
"gulp": "^3.9.1",
"gulp-angular-filesort": "^1.0.4",
"gulp-autoprefixer": "^2.0.0",
"gulp-concat": "^2.3.4",
"gulp-css-rebase-urls": "0.0.5",
"gulp-cssmin": "^0.1.6",
"gulp-eslint": "^1.0.0",
"gulp-filter": "^3.0.0",
"gulp-htmlmin": "^1.0.0",
"gulp-if": "^1.2.4",
"gulp-imagemin": "^2.0.0",
"gulp-inject": "^1.5.0",
"gulp-jade": "^1.0.0",
"gulp-jscs": "^3.0.0",
"gulp-jshint": "^1.8.4",
"gulp-less": "^3.0.1",
"gulp-load-plugins": "^0.10.0",
"gulp-modify-css-urls": "^0.2.0",
"gulp-ng-annotate": "^1.1.0",
"gulp-ng-html2js": "^0.2.0",
"gulp-notify": "^2.1.0",
"gulp-order": "^1.1.1",
"gulp-plumber": "^1.0.0",
"gulp-protractor": "^1.0.0",
"gulp-rename": "^1.2.0",
"gulp-rev": "^5.1.0",
"gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.5.1",
"gulp-template": "^4.0.0",
"gulp-tslint": "^3.1.2",
"gulp-uglify": "^1.0.0",
"gulp-util": "^3.0.8",
```

**Environment**

I'm developing in a 64-bit Windows 7 environment.

Let me know what you guys think or if there's any other resources I should check out. Thanks so much!

UPDATE: It turns out there's a number of different errors that the refresh terminates on, all of which are `file already exists` or `file not found`. I think this definitely implies that the commands are not set up correctly to rebuild. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try using rimraf or some such package to delete the folder in question before copying stuff back into it and making the directory again.

Comment: I was looking into this, but it turns out there's a number of files that need to be fixed, so I don't think this is the right approach. I added an update to the original post.